# How do you pass variables into Mirth Database Reader Channels for SQL expressions?

Tags: mirth

I can't find any documentation on how to manager parameters into Database Reader SQL statements?

-> this is a simplified example: I am not looking for scripting a variable to "yesterday" which is easy to express in SQL.  That's not the point.  I have have more complex variables in the actual SQL statement I'm trying to martial in.  I just want to know how to get variables into the SQL form if possible.

-> "you can just do that in JavaScript": the actual queries I need to run are about a hundred lines long, I don't want to maintain and debug a query build by concatenating strings and then deal with escaping 'quoted' things everywhere in the SQL.  I really prefer to maintain an actual SQL statement that copy/paste works in a SQL IDE.

How do we pass in parameters into the SQL block at the bottom of the Database Reader form?

```
SELECT patientsex, visitnumber, samplereceived_dt, sr_d, sr_t, orderpriority, orderrequestcode, orderrequestname
FROM mydata.somedata
WHERE sr_d = (${DateUtil.getCurrentDate('yyyyMMdd')})::integer;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For example

```
    var dbConn;
    
    try {
        dbConn = DatabaseConnectionFactory.createDatabaseConnection('','DB:Port\instance','user','pass');
    
    
        var paramList = new java.util.ArrayList();
        
        
        paramList.add($('patientId'));
        paramList.add($('lastName'));
        paramList.add($('firstName'));
        
        
        
        var result = dbConn.executeCachedQuery("SELECT * FROM patients WHERE patientid = ? AND lastname = ? AND firstname = ?) ",paramList);
    
    while (result.next()) {
        //you can reference by column index like so...
        //result.getString(1);
    
    }
    
    } finally {
        if (dbConn) { 
            dbConn.close();
        }
    }
```

Should be noted that the parameters you add to the list MUST be in order.

Comment: thanks for posting the parameterization snippet!  Any suggestions on how to read the SQL statement from an external location outside the javascript?  The SQL I'm trying to run is nearly 200 lines long, and I didn't want to string build that inside Javascript.

Comment: I edited my answer to include how to read the result, but I am not sure what you mean by "an external location outside javascript"...............you can use whatever you want to generate the inbound data prior to sending it into Mirth Connect.   If you are just wanting to avoid writing the entire query in Javascript, then @FrancisOchieng answer of using a stored procedure is the other piece you are looking for.

Comment: Hi. I did something very similar and simply returned the result var (com.mirth.connect.server.util.MirthCachedRosSet) but mirths seems not to convert it properly. How should I use re result?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is the feasible way to achieve this, with SQL statements defined inside Mirth connect or have the SQL statements bundled in a stored procedure then use SQL server's Exec command within Mirth connect to call the stored procedure while passing the parameters (interestingly using JavaScript).